# Can't catch the screen saver event

Tags: c++, windows, callback, screensaver

I'm trying to catch the screen saver event. This is my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "stdio.h"

#include <Windows.h>

#include <strsafe.h>

HHOOK _hook;

LRESULT CALLBACK HookCallback(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (nCode >= 0)
    {   
        LPMSG msg = (LPMSG)lParam;

        if(msg->message == WM_SYSCOMMAND)
        {
            if (msg->wParam == SC_SCREENSAVE)
            {
                std::cout<<"SC_SCREENSAVE\n";
            }
        }

    }

    return CallNextHookEx(_hook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

void SetHook()
{
    HINSTANCE hinstDLL = LoadLibrary(L"user32.dll");
    if (!(_hook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_GETMESSAGE,HookCallback,hinstDLL,0)))
    {
        std::cout<<"Failed to install hook!\n";
    }
}

void ReleaseHook()
{
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hook);
}


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    SetHook();


    // Don't mind this, it is a meaningless loop to keep a console application running.
    // I used this to test the keyboard hook functionality. If you want to test it, keep it in ;)
    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {

    }
    ReleaseHook();
    return 0;
}
```

The registration is successful. But I'm not catching the event. Not even getting inside the callback function. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sounds like a message-only window would suit your needs.

Comment: Chris, please can you explain or give me some reference of what suggested? Thanks!

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632599(v=vs.85).aspx#message_only

Answer (score -1):

Are you trying to create a screensaver or a program to screenshot the desktop? If you are making the screen saver, follow these.

A screensaver is a normal program with a `.scr` extension. A screensaver should accept the following command-line parameters.

> - \S  - Run in the full-screen mode
> - \P  - Run in the preview dialog box
> - \C  - Show the configuration dialog

However the `\P` switch is a bit different. It is followed by a colon and window handle of the system dialog box. For example, it could be `/P:1234567890`